# How to show error when writing a text that does not appear in the api?

Tags: python

I am programming a bot that what it does is display the information depending on whether it has those texts within the api, everything is fine up to here

The problem is as soon as I leave it blank it shows me all the links and in theory it should show an error and in this case it doesn't show it to me

and if i write any random text the error doesn't appear either

This is the code I'm using:

```
import json
import requests

args= input("Escribe:")

response = requests.get("https://jose89fcb.es/api/aumentos.php")
data = response.json()


for api in data['augments']:
    if args in api["name"]:
        print(api["icon"])
```

For this to work, you must write the "name" into the api: Example: Subidón máximo

How could I solve this problem? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a flag to check if there is any match found for the input text in the API data. If no match is found, print an error message.

```py
import json
import requests

args = input("Escribe: ")

if args.strip() == "":
    print("Error: The input is blank.")
    exit()

response = requests.get("https://jose89fcb.es/api/aumentos.php")
data = response.json()

match_found = False

for api in data['augments']:
    if args in api["name"]:
        print(api["icon"])
        match_found = True

if not match_found:
    print("Error: No matching data found in the API.")
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works, but now the problem is when I leave it blank, the links appear, and it shouldn't, how can I fix it?
https://i.imgur.com/zkuAHeZ.png

Comment: @noelia34563 You can add a simple condition to check if the input is blank before proceeding with the search in the API data. If the input is blank, print an error message and exit the program.
I updated my answer. See the new code.